# Represent bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$ by signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Here is the statement I'm trying to prove:

> Prove that if $\Lambda(f)\in C([0,1])$ is a bounded linear functional
> satisfying $|\Lambda(f)|\leq C\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$, then
> $$\Lambda(f)=\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\mu dx$$ where $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ is a
> signed measure with $\mu^+([0,1])+\mu^-([0,1])\leq C$.

What first comes to my mind is that a bounded linear functional $\Lambda(f)$ can be decomposed into $\Lambda^+-\Lambda^-$, difference of two nonnegative linear functionals. My idea is to correspond $\Lambda^+$ and $\Lambda^-$ uniquely to $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$, by Riesz representation, but I can only complete the positive part. For negative part, I cannot prove that $\Lambda^-(f)=\int_{[0,1]}fd\mu^-$. The reason is I cannot just simply use $\Lambda^-=\Lambda^+-\Lambda$, since $\Lambda$ is not known to be represented using measure $\mu$ within my context of proof.

My proof for the positive part, $\Lambda^+(f)=\int_{[0,1]}fd\mu^+$, is: since $\mu^+\perp\mu^-$, $\exists E$ measurable s.t. $\mu^+(E)=\mu^-(E^C)=0$. For $\leq$, apply $\Lambda^+(f)=\sup_{0\leq g\leq f}\Lambda(g)$ to it. For $\ge$, given $\varepsilon>0$, by Lusin theorem, $\exists\phi\in C([0,1])$ s.t. $\phi=f\chi_{E^C}$, except on a set $F\subset[0,1]$ with $\mu(F)<\varepsilon$. Choose $\psi=\min\{f,\phi\}$, and use $\Lambda^+(f)\ge\Lambda(\psi)$ to complete the rest.

Another approach I'm thinking of is to use the signed measure decomposition, and the control inequality $\mu^+([0,1])+\mu^-([0,1])\leq C=\sup_{f:\|f\|\le 1}|\Lambda(f)|$ to prove it. For this part, I don't know how to proceed further. I know that for bounded linear functional, the estimate $|\Lambda(f)|\leq\|\Lambda\|\|f\|_\infty$ holds, but how should I apply it? This only shows one side of the equality. And how should I prove the other side?

I'd like to see how to continue with the approach I mentioned above, since I think the method makes sense to me. Any comments and suggestions are welcome. If there are other approaches to prove this, they are also welcome. I'll add more if I have more progress on this. Thank you.

**A Clarification:** To prove this statement, I am assumed to know Riesz representation theorem for $C([0,1])$, and the aim is to prove a version of it for signed measures, where the measure satisfies the inequality.

Comment: As stated, the statement is false. You might want to revise it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Why? I don't see any flaws.

Comment: Take $\Lambda(f)=\int_0^1 f$, and $\mu=\delta_0$. Then you are saying that $\int_0^1 f=f(0)$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I made some changes for the statement.

Comment: You are missing the point. You cannot expect to prescribe a functional and a measure, and expect that they will satisfy your equality. The $\lambda$ and $\mu$ I gave you above still satisfy your conditions and not the equality.

Comment: I think I need to prove: The bounded linear functional has the integral representation, with the signed measure $\mu$ satisfying the inequality. I've edited the statement.

Comment: For your proof of the positive part, what are you actually trying to prove? And how does the decomposition of $\Lambda$ into $\Lambda^+,\Lambda^-$ work?

Comment: @supinf For the positive part, I proved that $\Lambda^+$ can be represented by $\mu^+$. The decomposition gives me the relation between these three, but I find it hard to prove that $\Lambda^-$ can be represented by $\mu^-$. Once I can prove this, together with the decomposition, I can prove the statement. But I think this may not be the correct way to do this.

Comment: Then I don't understand how you get $\mu^+$? Or is it given? Is $\mu$ given?

Comment: @supinf $\mu$ is given and can be decomposed into positive and negative variations.

Comment: @Mike: No. What you want is to find $\mu$ with the stated properties. I assume (but you don't say it!) that your context is that you already have Riesz-Markov, and you are trying to get a signed version of it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami That's probably the case. I'm also kind of confused by the wording of this problem. This comes from a problem solving session in my real analysis class. From your point of view, if I know Riesz representation, how can I prove the signed-measure version, and how to show that it satisfies the control inequality? Thank you so much for the interpretation.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Can you possibly write an answer to explain how to prove this, given that we know Riesz representation? Thank you.

Comment: Not really. This is Theorem 6.19 in Rudin, for instance, where it takes a couple pages for the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative proof. If $\Lambda$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$, then extend $\Lambda$ to a bounded linear functional $\Lambda_e$ on $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ with
$$
              \|\Lambda_e\|_{L^{\infty}[0,1]} = \|\Lambda\|_{C[0,1]}.
$$
Let $\mathcal{P}=\{x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots <x_n\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ with norm $\|\mathcal{P}\|$. If $f\in C[a,b]$, define
$$
          f_{\mathcal{P}}=f(x_1^*)\chi_{[x_1,x_2)}+\cdots + f(x_{n-1}^*)\chi_{[x_{n-1},x_{n}]}
$$
Then $f_{\mathcal{P}}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ as $\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0$. Note that
$$
        \Lambda_e(f_{\mathcal{P}})=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(x_k^*)\Delta \gamma_k,\;\;\gamma(x)=\Lambda_e(\chi_{[0,x]}).
$$
The function $\gamma$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$. In the limit,
$$
                \Lambda_e(f)=\int_0^1f(u)d\gamma(u).
$$
You can extend $\gamma$ to a signed Borel measure, and be more general. The basic representation is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral of the continuous function $f$ with respect to a function of bounded variation on $[0,1]$. After that you can apply measure theory to decompose into positive and negative measures, for example, using this as a building block.

Comment: Can you explain or add more details on how to extend $\gamma$ to signed measure, i.e. how to go from the integral representation wrt function of BV to decomposition of the measure? Also, I am assumed to know Riesz theorem. The first part of the proof seems like a proof of Riesz theorem for $C([0,1])$?

Comment: @Mike : Use the total variation $|\gamma|$ of $\gamma$ to decompose $\gamma=\frac{1}{2}(|\gamma|(t)+\gamma(t))-\frac{1}{2}(|\gamma|(t)-\gamma(t))$

Comment: I see. Is the first part a proof of Riesz theorem for $C([0,1])$?

Comment: @Mike : Yes, it is.